# How to multiply two matrices (from input)?

Tags: assembly, multidimensional-array, x86, nasm, matrix-multiplication

I want to get n and define two n*n matrices and then get them as input and then multiply them but I don't know how to get two matrices as input.

```
section .data
    input_format: db "%d", 0
    n: dd 1
    array: times n dd 0.0
```

I tried this to define an array with size n but it causes some error.

Comment: The error for `array: times n dd 0.0` is that `times` expects an assembly time value as a counter. `times` can not use the  runtime value of `n`. Use a count that is big enough to support whatever it is that you want to allow for `n` as inputted by the user.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52406492/x86-sse-optimization-hints-for-4x4-float-matrixvector-product) does not answer your question directly, but makes sense to have a look at. I guess this will help you get some insights.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword you’re looking for is [row‑ and column‑major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order).
A matrix is essentially an

```pascal
array[rowMinimum..rowMaximum, columnMinimum..columnMaximum] of baseType
```

In row‑major order you store elements belonging to the same row next to each other.
In other words the right‑most dimension of an `array` (as per above declaration) increases first.
To put this in *unnecessarily* verbose code, a 2 × 2 matrix:

```
matrix_a:
.left_column_top_row:     db 42   ; In mathematical notation:
.right_column_top_row:    db  3   ;        ⎡ 42,  3 ⎤
.left_column_bottom_row:  db -9   ;    A ≔ ⎢        ⎥
.right_column_bottom_row: db 99   ;        ⎣ −9, 99 ⎦
```

First you achieve your task with static data.
If it works correctly, you can transition to dynamic data.
Query *n*, set aside enough memory space, and prompt for *n²* elements, preferably in row‑major order, because it is most natural in a left‑to‑right writing system, and pass the data to the function.